# Some random image transaction showing on New Relic for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, newrelic

I recently configured New Relic for my server which runs our retail site powered by Magento and blog powered by Wordpress.

The most time consuming transaction I see is "/image" and I am unable to understand what it is and how to fix it.

Wordpress runs on `www.mydomain.com/blog/`

Please check the following screenshots of my New Relic panel.

- **Transactions**

[image: /image is 54.4% on the time consumption chart.]

- **Server breakdown**

[image]

- **Transaction traces**

[image]

Can you help me understand what is happening so I can debug and fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem after digging into attachments.

After uploading media, Wordpress creates an attachment page for them, like so:

`www.mydomain.com/blog/?attachment_id=xxxx`

The template loaded by Wordpress for this type of page is:

`/wp-content/themes/your-theme/image.php`

There were TONS of comments on the page and it was making close to 4300 HTTP calls to my server per each attachment page.

### Solution:

I simply redirected these pages to the home page since I do not want such pages to show up.